# Error saying file is already open when writing to a file

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with fields that i am saving to the text file.

On that same form I have a button that allows you to view what you saved prior from that text file

When i hit the button it reads the textfile and displays on a datagrid.

This code is what is displaying to the datagrid

```
Dim reader As StreamReader
    reader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\John\Desktop\tickets.txt")
    Dim a As String
    Dim results() As String
    Do
        a = reader.ReadLine
        results = a.Split(vbTab)
        dgv.Rows.Add(results(0), results(1), results(2), results(3), results(4), results(5))
        ' Code here
        '
    Loop Until a Is Nothing

    reader.Close()
    reader.Dispose()
```

this code saves to the file

```
 Dim file As StreamWriter
    file = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\John\Desktop\tickets.txt", True)
    file.WriteLine(txtname.Text & vbTab & dtdate.Text & vbTab & txttime.Text & vbTab & txtwho.Text & vbTab & txtproblem.Text & vbTab & txtresolution.Text)
    file.Close()
```

When I read the records first then try to save them I keep getting the error the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I closed both the reader and writer, and am not sure why this is happeneing

Comment: Did you have the file open in Word? That will cause this error.

Comment: nope nothing has the file open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better code, are you sure your loop was ending?

Write:

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\John\Desktop\tickets.txt"
If File.Exists(path) Then
 Using sw As New StreamWriter(path, True)
  'code
 End Using' closes and disposes for you
End If
```

Read:

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\John\Desktop\tickets.txt"
If File.Exists(path) Then
 Dim results As New List(Of String)
 Using sr As New StreamReader(path)
  While Not sr.EndOfStream()
   results.Add(sr.Readline())
   'better than do loop
  End While
 End Using' closes and disposes for you
End If

For Each line In results
  'add to DGV
Next
```

Comment: Thanks,  I guess the loop wasn't ending ;)

Comment: Could set a Boolean to check if file exists once and then use it where you would need it, just a suggestion; redundancy can be an issue sometimes.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR, I was doing that as if they were in separate methods.

Comment: Don't use File.Exists